# Sitecore not setting cache directives on request headers

Tags: caching

We have upgraded from Sitecore 9.3 to 10.3 which uses `Headless services`. Our instance is on `sitecore managed cloud`.

On our 10.3 instance, we do not see the `Cache-control` and `pragma` directives on request headers.

As per sitecore documentation we have verified the **DisableBrowserCache** setting and its already set to **true**.

Is there any other configuration required for this?

Comment: Could you please check 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/response?view=aspnetcore-7.0 

and

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47224561/iis-asp-net-responds-with-cache-control-private-for-all-requests

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, verify that the `<setting name="DisableBrowserCaching" value="true"/>` is set in your `Sitecore.config` file.

For Sitecore Managed Cloud , caching is handled by the CDN. Check your CDN configuration to ensure caching headers are enabled there.

Also you can `clear the browser cache` to ensure that the old cached responses are not being used.

Lastly,if none of above helps, suggest to raise a support ticket with Sitecore Managed Cloud team.